# SQL injection vulnerability to add more balance?

Tags: sql, sql-injection

Let's say I have this SQL statement:

```
stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO TUNEUSER (USERNAME,PASSWORD,BALANCE) VALUES ('"
        + daf.getString("username")
        + "','"
        + daf.getString("password")
        + "',0.00)");
```

and the application has a username and password field.

How can SQL injection be used to increased the balance from "0.00" to whatever you want?

Comment: By injecting code to modify that SQL statement.  Do you understand what SQL injection is and how it works?

Answer (score 1):

Set the password to something like this:

```
mypassword', 1000); --
```